# have problems to do or have problems doing?

Tags: sentence-construction

Another question. The two sentences below:

- I have some Maths problems to solve.
- I have some Maths problems solving.

Which one is correct? Or both of them are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have some Maths problems to solve.

This is the right one

*To solve*, in this sentence, means your Math problems have to be solved, i.e, you have to answer them.

Using -*ING* in the second sentence doesn't make any sense.

'*I have some Math problems solving*' means You have some Math problems that are solving something (something which wasn't mentioned in your sentence), i.g, *I have some Math problems solving my grades* = You have some Math problems that will help you with your grades.

Or let's change this sentence a little bit so I can explain you it better:

> *I have some friends* **solving** *my Math problems*

- My friends are answering my Math problems.

> I have some Math problems to solve / to be solved

- You have Math problems that you need to answer.